# How to filter and take only one download link?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851"
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)

for d in soup.select("p.start-download [href]"):
        print d['href']
```

When I run this code,it give me many download link.
How can I only take only one of the download link given?

Comment: You could extract them to a list and then iterate at your leisure. Or you could break after you find the first link. Is there any constraints on the specific link you're looking for or will any do?

Comment: oh yes, I could break it. nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use your given code, you will not be able to take hold of the links and use them. Use the following code instead:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17851"
pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)

urls = []
for d in soup.select("p.start-download [href]"):
    urls.append(d.attrs['href'])

print urls[0]
```

If you use the above code, then you can use the links themselves in other parts of the program. You may also do this using a lit comprehension:

```
urls = [d['href'] for d in soup.select("p.start-download [href]")]

print urls[0]
```

You can then iterate over `urls` to get the url you want, or just use an index to get your link. Either way, this is more flexible than just printing a link. For example if you did not want to full installation, and just wanted some other package or perhaps the package for XP instead of Vista, 7 and 8 (using your urls here as an example).

Answer (score 1):

```
for d in soup.select("p.start-download [href]"):
        print d['href']
        break
```

will stop after the first link